# C function argument to set values for global variables?

Tags: c, function, pointers, arguments, return-value

I am creating functions that could declare values to the argument variable passed by the function.

For example,from my server.c file:

```
int sfd;    //socket file descriptor
int listenv;  //if listen
struct sockaddr_in serverAddress;   //server address

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) { //argv[0] == server //argv[1] == port number

    listenv = setServer(argv[1],serverAddress,sfd);
            //int port = ntohs(serverAddress.sin_port);
            printf("sfd = %d port = %d\n", sfd, ntohs(serverAddress.sin_port));
    while (listenv == 0) {
    }
}
```

And from my serverAPI.h file:

```
int setServer (char * portn,struct sockaddr_in saddr,int sfd) {

    saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    saddr.sin_port = (int)htons(atoi(portn));


    sfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sfd < 0)
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    printf("Successfully opened socket sfd = %d\n",sfd);

    if (bind(sfd, (struct sockaddr *) &saddr, sizeof(saddr)) == -1 )
        error("ERROR on binding");
    printf("Successfully Binded on port %d\n", ntohs(saddr.sin_port));//show correct port number

    int listenv;
    if((listenv = listen(sfd,5)) < 0)
        error("ERROR on listening");
    //print message to show connection has been made
    printf("Ready and Listening...");

    return (listenv);
}
```

This is what I have...

And I expected that from the 'setServer' function, that passed variable (i.e. ServerAddress and sfd),values would have been declared by the function, but it has not...

So the return value inside setServer function is:

```
serverAddress.sin_port = 12345
sfd = 3
listenv = 0
```

and from the main:

```
serverAddress.sin_port = 0
sfd = 0
listenv = 0
```

as it has been listed as globally.

What would I have to set as argument for setServer so that it can set values for the global variable?

Comment: `setServer` expects a `struct sockaddr_in` as second parameter. You pass a `struct sockaddr_in*`. Typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As C passes parameters by *copy-by-value*, when modifying `sfd` or `saddr`, you only modify the parameters itsself, that is, copies of the passed parameters. You need to pass pointers to actually modify the variables. Declare `setServer` like this:

```
int setServer (char * portn, struct sockaddr_in* saddr, int* sfd);
```

Add dereferencing operators:

```
saddr->sin_family = AF_INET;
saddr->sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
saddr->sin_port = (int)htons(atoi(portn));


*sfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (*sfd < 0)
    error("ERROR opening socket");
printf("Successfully opened socket sfd = %d\n",*sfd);

if (bind(*sfd, (struct sockaddr *) saddr, sizeof(*saddr)) == -1 )
    error("ERROR on binding");
printf("Successfully Binded on port %d\n", ntohs(saddr->sin_port));//show correct port number

int listenv;
if((listenv = listen(*sfd,5)) < 0)
    error("ERROR on listening");
//print message to show connection has been made
printf("Ready and Listening...");

return (listenv);
```

And call `setServer` with **pointers**:

```
listenv = setServer(argv[1],&serverAddress,&sfd);
```

Comment: does that mean that I have to declare the global variables like:
int *sfd;    //socket file descriptor
int *listenv;  //if listen
struct sockaddr_in *serverAddress;   //server address
???

Comment: how about for listenv?
If I set listenv == -1 inside setServer function, the listenv variable inside main still has a value of 0 (as initialized by the global variable)
@cad

Comment: @YongHeeLee If you return `-1` from `setServer` it is assigned to the `listenv` in `main`, so that should work as expected.

Comment: @YongHeeLee No, the definitions are fine.